# How to tell RStudio to autocomplete my function's arguments with package names?

Tags: r, autocomplete, package, rstudio, r-infer

[According to RStudio:](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/205273297-Code-Completion)

> In addition, certain functions, such as library() and require(), expect package names for completions. RStudio automatically infers whether a particular function expects a package name and provides those names as completion...

My question is: how? I'm writing a custom function that takes package names as arguments, yet RStudio's only completing the arguments with object & function names, and I can't tell what it is about the `library()` and `require()` code that RStudio is picking up on.

My function is:

```
unpack <- function(...,
                   lib   = NULL,
                   repos = getOption("repos")) {
  pkgs <- sapply(match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)[-1], as.character)
  new.pkgs <-
    pkgs[!(
      pkgs %in% installed.packages(lib.loc = lib)[, "Package"]
    )]
  if (length(new.pkgs))
    install.packages(new.pkgs,
                     lib   = lib,
                     repos = repos)
  sapply(pkgs, require,
         lib.loc = lib,
         character.only = TRUE)
}
```

Comment: RStudio does a lot of contextual inference based on the function name you are typing. Not looking at their source, my guess is that they know you just typed in `library(`, so auto-completion at this point should include package names, not just the function's named arguments.

Comment: There has been related discussion (of extending RStudio's auto-completion behavior) here: https://github.com/ropensci/unconf17/issues/52, though no apparent activity in 1.5 years.

Comment: @r2evans Ah - so the answer might be that RStudio has coded exceptions just for functions named `library` and `require`. I guess I could try and mask one of those two... lol

Comment: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/71fc26a0c42a275bd3c689db82f127a4a499f003/src/gwt/src/org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/console/shell/assist/RCompletionManager.java#L845  /  https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/93a7722965e3f46a2b5695b2d609cd10d2fee9db/src/cpp/session/modules/SessionRCompletions.R#L2071-L2080

Comment: Perfect, thanks @hrbrmstr ! Not the answer I was hoping for, but the exact answer I needed. I actually did just try out just naming my function `library`, and, yep, works great. Feels highly improper, but when the laws become unjust, the just become outlaws.

Comment: Yes, mask the functions, what could possibly go wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @hrbrmstr pointed out, there's both Java and R code that specifically name the four functions that autocomplete with package names, so the solution is to either mask one of those and cross your fingers, or add your function's name to those lists in both source files (or maybe just the R, I wonder).

Answer (score 2):

I recently created a package which has few more autocompletion (though totally experimental) (as extra code only).

It can be seen here https://github.com/r-rudra/patch/blob/main/inst/embedded/usecases.R

Maybe soon enough all these will be available by default in RStudio.

Check [this comment](https://github.com/ropensci/unconf18/issues/65#issuecomment-723088752)